# In which chapter did the Genei Ryodan fight the chimera ants?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In the manga, when did the Genei Ryodan fight the chimera ants?

Comment: Do you know anything more specific about what was going on, such as where he was or who was with him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spiders first make their appearance in Chapter 224 of the manga. Needless to say a fight follows shortly after (next chapter).

[image: They're back~]